# Issue with TokBox Audio Session with CallKit

Tags: ios, swift, opentok, tokbox, callkit

I have implemented the opentok in my app, and did all necessary implementation which is required. I have been gone through sample code and did exactly same, by calling destination phone, the call reached perfectly, then issues comes.

1. Sometimes call connected to both device but most of the times not, receiver phone started the call with time counting but it has not been connected with voice chat in either way.
2. Some times loud speaker become active automatically in receiver phone and also by tapping it has not been disable.

Does anybody went through this situation and resolved it ? A
Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using callkit for voice calls then follow below solution to make your audio session active.

while making call or answering call :

- Deactivate audio session.
- initiate your audio session again.
- answer/make call.